# Can a database be replicated to an EC2 instance from outside Amazon?

Tags: amazon-ec2, replication, master-slave

I am looking to set up replication which will have a master in my local environment and a slave in the Amazon environment.

I am able to set up replication successfully for two EC2 instances, but failing to do so if the master is outside the Amazon environment. I changed the security group to have port 3306 open but that didn't change anything.

Are there any other changes to be done? Anyone has a similar setup? Is this possible at all?

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL?  Can you connect from the EC2 instance to your master database port?  What is the specific error message you get when you turn on replication?

Comment: I am using MySQL. Just checked 'telnet [machine IP] 3306' from ec2 instance and it is timing out. So it looks like it is not able to connect to 3306 port even though IP tables are stopped. I have to look further to see if there are other firewalls. Thanks for guiding in the right direction.

Comment: I had the replication going now. Thanks. I have another question regarding the security of data transferred. Is there a way to encrypt the traffic between ec2 instance and local machine? How secure is this kind of setup? Our plan is to have replication servers going in amazon for all our production servers.

Comment: Unless you know what you're doing, it can be very risky.  You are opening up a port on your master database server and passing the username/password in clear text over the Internet.  One option is to use an ssh tunnel so that the traffic is encrypted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, the database port on master machine is opened only for the slave ec2 machine. Also, the security group for the ec2 instance has the database port open only to the master machine. So I assumed it is a secure connection. But I will look into using an ssh tunnel as our intention is to have the traffic encrypted as well.

Comment: If you are using IP address restriction, you should make sure that the EC2 instance is using an Elastic IP address. Otherwise, your instance could be terminated and another account could start an instance at the same external IP address.  Also, just because you restrict access to a given IP address does not mean that the data transmitted between the hosts is secure.

Comment: The instance is indeed using an Elastic IP. Thanks for noting ssh tunnel in your previous comment. Based on that, I looked up more to find out about 'SSH encrypted MySQL replication' which should make the data secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work fine as long as all the ports on your local network are open and forwarded correctly. Have you made sure that your database is accessible via a remote network, more info/troubleshooting info can be found here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-problems.html

Comment: Yes, it looks like port issues on local machine. Thanks for the information. It has not been fixed yet but hopefully will get there.